# Which classes in $\mathrm{H}^4(B\mathrm{Exceptional}; \mathbb{Z})$ are classical characteristic classes?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, group-cohomology, characteristic-classes

Let $G$ be a compact connected Lie group. Recall that $\mathrm{H}^4(\mathrm{B}G;\mathbb{Z})$ is then a free abelian group of finite rank. Let us say that a class $c \in \mathrm{H}^4(\mathrm{B}G;\mathbb{Z})$ is *classical* if it is in the image of restriction along a map $G \to J$ where $J$ is a classical Lie group, i.e. a quotient of $\mathrm{Spin}(N)$, $\mathrm{SU}(N)$, or $\mathrm{Sp}(N)$. The classical classes are essentially the Chern and (fractional) Pontryagin classes of linear representations of $G$. Let us furthermore say that a class is *virtually classical* if it is a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of classical classes.

**Remark:** Not every virtually classical class is classical. Indeed, $\mathrm{H}^4(\mathrm{B}G;\mathbb{Z})$ has a cone of *positive* classes, namely the ones that determine negative-definite pairings under the canonical map $\mathrm{H}^4(\mathrm{B}G;\mathbb{Z}) \to \mathrm{H}^4(\mathrm{B}G;\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathrm{Sym}^2(\mathfrak{g})^G$. Restriction along homomorphisms preserves positivity. Suppose $c_1,c_2$ are nonzero classical classes on $G_1,G_2$. Then $c_1 \ominus c_2 \in \mathrm{H}^4(BG_1 \times BG_2)$ does not have a definite sign, and so is not classical, but it is virtually classical.

**Question 0:** If $G$ is simple, is every virtually classical class classical?

When $G$ is already a classical Lie group, then all classes are classical, although it is certainly a fun game to understand the restriction maps between various groups. For $G = \mathrm{G}_2$, the seven-dimensional representation $\mathrm{G}_2 \to \mathrm{Spin}(7)$ is an isomorphism of $\mathrm{H}^4$, and so all classes in $\mathrm{H}^4(B\mathrm{G}_2; \mathbb{Z})$ are classical.

**Question 1:** For the other exceptional Lie groups $G = \mathrm{F}_4, \mathrm{E}_6,\mathrm{E}_7,\mathrm{E}_8$, which classes in $\mathrm{H}^4(\mathrm{B}G;\mathbb{Z})$ are classical? Which are virtually classical?

This is easy if the answer to Question 0 is "yes", because I'm pretty sure that the smallest (positive) classical class is achieved by the smallest-dimensional representation. (In terms of the smallest positive class, the smallest classical classes are, I think, $3, 6, 6?,30$.) But I could imagine a situation where there is some funny cancellation and there are virtually classical classes smaller than any classical class.

---

**Edit:** I'm pretty sure that the answer to Question 0 must be "no", modulo my mistakes in calculations. First, recall that the *Dynkin index* of a map $G \to J$ of simple simply connected Lie groups is the numerical value of the induced map $\mathbb{Z} = \mathrm{H}^4(BJ) \to \mathrm{H}^4(BG) = \mathbb{Z}$. The inclusions $D_4 \subset F_4 \subset E_6 \subset E_7 \subset E_8$ all have Dynkin index $1$, and the adjoint map $G \to \mathrm{Spin}(\mathfrak{g})$ has Dynkin index the dual Coxeter number $h^\vee$.

The Dynkin index of a complex representation $V : G \to \mathrm{SU}(N)$ is called the *Chern class* $c_2(V)$ (except maybe it is $-c_2$). For a Spin representation $V : G \to \mathrm{Spin}(N)$, $N \geq 5$, it is the *fractional Pontryagin class* $\frac{p_1}2(V)$, and for a symplectic representation $G \to \mathrm{Sp}(N)$ it is the *quaternionic Pontryagin class*, which I will call $q_1(V)$. (Wikipedia calls it also $p_1(V)$, which is confusing.) The maps $\mathrm{Spin}(N) \to \mathrm{SU}(N)$ and $\mathrm{SU}(N) \to \mathrm{Sp}(N)$ each have Dynkin index $2$, whereas the maps $\mathrm{Sp}(N) \to \mathrm{SU}(2N)$ and $\mathrm{SU}(N) \to \mathrm{Spin}(2N)$ each have Dynkin index $1$. (Note that, like a topologist, I write $\mathrm{Sp}(N)$ for the group of quaternionic automorphisms of $\mathbb{H}^N$. Representation theorists sometimes call this group $\mathrm{Sp}(2N)$, because maps into it are $2N$-dimensional symplectic representations.)

In any case, the adjoint representation of $\mathrm{E}_7$ has fractional Pontryagin class $\frac{p_1}2(\mathbf{133}) = h^\vee(\mathrm{E}_7) = 18$, so $18 \in \mathrm{H}^4(B\mathrm{E}_7)$ is classical. The smallest representation of $\mathrm{E}_7$ is the $56$-dimensional symplectic representation $\mathbf{56} : \mathrm{E}_7 \to \mathrm{Sp}(28)$. I claim that $q_1(\mathbf{56}) = 12$, which means, I think, that $6$ is virtually classical but not classical.

To justify the claim, I need to compute $q_1(\mathbf{56})$. I claimed already that the map $\mathrm{Sp}(28) \to \mathrm{SU}(56)$ that forgets the symplectic structure has Dynkin index $1$, which is to say $q_1(\mathbf{56}) = -c_2(\mathbf{56})$.
Now note that $\mathrm{E}_6 \subset \mathrm{E}_7$ has Dynkin index $1$, so it suffices to compute $c_2(\mathbf{56})|_{\mathrm{E}_6} = c_2(\mathbf{56}|_{\mathrm{E}_6}) = c_2(\mathbf{27} \oplus \overline{\mathbf{27}} \oplus \mathbf{1} \oplus \mathbf{1}) = 2 c_2(\mathbf{27})$.

So my claim amounts to the claim that $c_2(\mathbf{27}) = 6 \in \mathrm{H}^4(B\mathrm{E}_6)$. I can compute this by restricting further along the Dynkin-index-$1$ map $\mathrm{F}_4 \subset \mathrm{E}_6$, where $\mathbf{27} = \mathbf{26} \oplus 1$. So I want to compute $c_2(\mathbf{26}) = -2\frac{p_1}2(\mathbf{26}) \in \mathrm{H}^4(B\mathrm{F}_4)$.

So my claim amounts to the claim that $\frac{p_1}2(\mathbf{26}) = 3 \in \mathrm{H}^4(B\mathrm{F}_4)$. To compute this, restrict further along the Dynkin-index-$1$ map $\mathrm{D}_4 \subset \mathrm{F}_4$, where $\mathbf{26}$ splits as a sum of the three $8$-dimensional representations $\mathrm{D}_4 = \mathrm{Spin}(8) \to \mathrm{Spin}(8)$ (plus some trivial representations).

In summary, I know that $12$ and $18$ are both classical classes for $\mathrm{E}_7$, and so $6$ is a virtually classical class for $\mathrm{E}_7$. I have a hard time believing that it is actually classical. Well, I have an OK time believing that I made a mistake in the calculations, especially if I am wrong about the relation between Chern and quaternionic Pontryagin classes. And I don't see how some large representation of $\mathrm{E}_7$ will have small characteristic classes, but I don't have a proof that this cannot happen...

---

**Comment:** It is interesting that the numbers $3, 6, 6, 30$ for $F_4,E_6,E_7,E_8$ are also the largest square-free factors of the dual Coxeter numbers of these groups $(9, 12, 18, 30)$. Furthermore, if I ignore the prime $p=2$, then these are the only simple simply connected groups with torsion in their cohomology, and only at these primes (this is a result of Serre, I think). Ignoring the prime $p=2$ might make sense, since the characteristic classes for the classical series are all the same up to a factor of $2$: after inverting $2$, I could have just asked to understand the "Chern subring" (in degree $4$) of $\mathrm{H}^\bullet(BG)$.

Comment: This isn't going to particularly help you resolve your question, but as regards the Comment, I think it was Borel who closed the book on determining torsion primes, particularly in this paper: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.tmj/1178244298. There is earlier joint work with Serre, though: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02564557.

Comment: @jdc Thank you!